# Proguard in release mode

Tags: android, sinch

I am installing app through studio I guess that's **instant** run

I guess my code is **not** **shrinking** since my apk is still **16.1 MB** large and nothing in it except sinch library..

```
buildTypes {    
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

Don't know if I have to add this in instant run or not.....

```
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
 }
```

but when use debug it shows this :

> Gradle build process failed with "Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'. > Warnings found
>   during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress
>   them." - Proguard #206

Don't know if my app is in **release** mode if it is not in release mode then I guess I will receive **same** error when I am in release mode but if this is a problem of **debugger** and I am already in **release** mode then why my app isn't **shrinking**?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message you should use -dontwarn in your **proguard-rules.pro** file in your app module

Example:

```
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.json.JSONObject
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.Logger
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.Level
-dontwarn org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
-dontwarn org.slf4j.Logger
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder
-dontwarn org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.MinimalField
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody
-dontwarn org.apache.http.entity.mime.MIME
-dontwarn android.support.v4**
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Google what you should suppress for libraries you use in your project,

good luck

Comment: But I have jniLibs which is quite large and it has 4 folders armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 and x86_64 since I am using sinch only for app-app calling I guess it is including all functiionlity for app-phone calling,messaging,etc which sinch provided in its sdk don't know how to exclude those.....

Comment: I found this in sinch proguard txt 
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

Comment: and you have seen that I am minifying only in release so if I run this app from studio install it on my mobile share it with other mobile using shareIT and see the apk size what would it be? will it be reduced or not ? remember I am using shrinker and minify in release

Comment: Not working it was 16.1 MB before and 16.1 MB after sorry man

Comment: you used minifyEnabled = true in debug mode also, so your app should be shrinking or giving the same error message in debug mode also, if that doesn't happen make sure run execute AssembleDebug gradle command and nothing else, that way it should be easier to see whats wrong with proguard rules

Comment: Okay I have to do using command line by going into the project directory ....I'll inform you with the the problem